# Nestjs starter hangs when deployed to Fargate without logging on cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nestjs, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

Having some trouble deploying an empty nestjs project on a fargate cluster.
Every other container works correctly and networking is fine. The main problem is that the nestjs app simply hangs without writing any log after logging nestjs start.
Application is an empty project with appModule and no other code added so no db connection or other services connected.
Using a simple dockerfile:

`# Base image
FROM node:18-alpine as dev

## Create app directory

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

## A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied

COPY package*.json ./

## Install app dependencies

RUN npm install

## Bundle app source

COPY . .

## Build

RUN npm run build

## Start the server using the production build

CMD [ "node", "dist/main.js" ]`

Now the only output that I have is "nest start" and the container becomes unresponsive failing health checks hence the deployment. As soon as the code hits the bootstrap of the app (Nestfactory.create(AppModule) the logging stops and the container becomes unresponsive.
Cleary, works fine building and running the container locally and/or with docker-compose.
Even pulling the images from ecr registry (where i push those images for running them in fargate) and executing locally works fine.

I did make sure to diagnose if it was something related to configuration/networking/infrastructure but every other container works (simple nginx, node with http-server, other node applications, etc...)
Even more, no logging about starting the application with the usual "Starting the application.... Nestfactory" is seen in the log.
I also tried to use some beefy task definition in case nestjs was struggling with memory and cpu but the application simply hangs there and dies later since the ecs daemon kills it due to health checks failing and/or sigkilled due to go out of memory.

For information, I'm using fargate with arm64 cpu and images built and pushed to a private ecr repository on a macbook m1 so there's no architecture incompatibility (and if it's not compatible the containers don't start at all) but also building x86 with fargate amd64 fails in the same manner.

Can be a full application or even the bare minimum nestjs project, resulting failure is always the same
Now I would expect that if it was some compatibility issues with docker container and/or nodejs version something would be written to log but the app simply hangs and the container becomes unresponsive so I cannot even inspect it sshing in the container via executeAction from cli.

Due to not having logs other than my console logs before app bootstrap, I don't really have much to diagnose the problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Even we faced the same issue.We have solved it by Modifying Docker:
FROM node:20 as node-docker

WORKDIR  /app

#Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

RUN  npm ci
#Bundle application code
COPY . .

## Build app

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "dist/src/main.js" ]

Modify your dist/main to dist/src/main.js ...

Check your Dist Folder Once ..

Please consider checking : Any SSM or env Variable issues .